# How to mock this.setState function of react.js using jest+enzyme

Tags: enzyme, jestjs, react-dnd

I am new to react and jest. I am writing unit test for react dnd component that uses dargsource and dropitem. I am writing snapshot test for it using enzyme, but it gives me error : dragdropmanager is required.

Can anybody help me resolving this error. Also, there is setState function , how we can mock this function using jest :

```
function testdragitem(WrapperComponent) {
    return class extends WrapperComponent {
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                 window.setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({ isDisabled: nextProps.isDragging });
            });
        }
```

If anyone has working example of jest test that is written for drag and drop component, please share reference link that could help. I read few links that define ways to test but there is no example for same that could make it clear.

Thanks !!